# Why do I get "undefined method `visit'"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test my app controller with RSpec on Ruby on Rails. I'm not using Capybara (since many use it). This is my spec test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UserController do

it "create new user" do
    get :create, :user => { :email => 'foo@example.com', :name => 'userexample' }
    flash[:notice] = 'new user was successfully created.'
end
  describe "signup" do

  before { visit new_user_registration_path }

  let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

  describe "with invalid information" do
  it "should not create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
  end
 end

describe "with valid information" do
  before do
    fill_in "Name",         :with=> "Example User"
    fill_in "Email",        :with=> "user@example.com"
    fill_in "Password",     :with=> "foobar"
    fill_in "Confirmation", :with=> "foobar"
  end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
   end
 end
end
```

Here is my `Usercontroller`:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
def index

end

def new
     @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to user_session_path
    else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
end

end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #redirect_to @user
end
end
```

When I tested it, I got the error: `undefined method 'visit'`:

```
Failure/Error: before { visit new_user_registration_path }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x132cefbc0>
 # ./spec/controllers/user_controller_spec.rb:11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to use Capybara for this function. I think your tests are not in the right place. You must to do requests specs for that. It's not for controllers specs. See the doc : https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/.

Comment: well i have to test the controllers, and what are requests specs?

Comment: Did you have search it in the doc? It's basicly the same thing than integration tests : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing. It's used to test integration beetween your views, controllers and models.

Comment: do you know any page that i can learn to test with rspec?, because i dont know so much.

Comment: See this : http://www.codeschool.com/courses/testing-with-rspec or this http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=rspec+. There is a lot of resource on this subject.